# Como armazenar "link direto" para uma imagem utilizando Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase

Preciso acessar uma imagem armazenada no Firebase Storage por um link direto, ex:

```
http://myfirebasehost.com/storage/imgIwant.png
```

Pelo que sei, só é possível esse tipo de URL utilizando o protocolo `gs://`, no entanto, ele não é acessível por link, apenas na api do SDK.

Preciso de uma solução exatamente como descrevi acima utilizando a plataforma Firebase, se não for possível, aceito outras sugestões.

Meu código tem constantes que são links para imagens. Acontece que, se eu quiser atualizar essa imagem, terei de fazer um novo deploy. Ao invés disso quero que a imagem se atualize na mesma URL. Seria impossível fazer isso com o firebase (até onde sei) porque a URL fornecida pelo Storage não é acessível por link.

Outra alternativa talvez fosse converter uma imagem para base64 e armazenar na Database, mas ficaria muito extenso e inviável.

Comment: Você teria problemas imensos de cache com essa sua solução. Mais interessante seria atualizar um dado remoto que contém a URL. O cache de texto é muito menos persistente.

Comment: O Firebase até gera um link persistente que abre no navegador mas por algum motivo da erro com o plugin Cordova social share.

Comment: Um dado que não tá salvo na aplicação. Um dado salvo no Firebase. Salve a URL no Firebase e faça sua aplicação buscar essa URL. Daí você altera a URL quando precisar mudar a foto. Isso é mais interessante do que deixar a URL fixa por causa do problema de cache que você vai ter se fizer isso.

Comment: Creio que o que você procura é o [Download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?hl=pt-br#download_data_via_url) (que também pode ser obtido na consola do Firebase). Para não ter de fazer deploys de actualização, você pode armazenar este url na sua database.

Comment: Bom, o jeito que fiz pode não ser o certo, mas vou mostrar como fiz: Para isso eu usei o comando getDownloadURL, por exemplo: [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWPv3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWPv3.png)